# Button image changing on UITableViewCell after Scrolling in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin

In attendance module using button in UITableViewCell. This button is using 3 different image base on condition. If Student parent showing green image, if absent showing gray image and if withdraw subject then showing red image.

Except withdraw student, teacher can marked attendance. But problem is that when I scroll down and then up its images are changing randomly.

Check attached images. First screen showing all are parent. But when without change any attendance I scroll down and then up then button image is changed.

image1 = All are parent

image2 = After Scroll down

image3 = After Scroll Up

Code for Get Cell:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Called by the TableView to get the actual UITableViewCell to render for the particular row
    /// </summary>
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        string cellIndentifier = "studentIndentifier";
        // request a recycled cell to save memory
        ipadStudentAttendanceTableViewCell cell = (ipadStudentAttendanceTableViewCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIndentifier);

        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        //if (cell == null)
        //    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIndentifier) as ipadStudentAttendanceTableViewCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.UpdateCell(tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading
                , tableItems[indexPath.Row].Flags
                , tableItems[indexPath.Row].id
                , tableItems[indexPath.Row].lbl1);
        }
        return cell;
    }


public void UpdateCell(string Student, bool IsAttendance, string StudentID, string Registration)
    {
        //uiSwitch.
        lblStudent.Text = Student;
        lblID.Text = StudentID;
        lblRegistered.Text = Registration;
        var item = AttributeItems.studentAttendanceInfo.Find(f => f.StudentID == StudentID);

        lblStudent.TextColor = AttributeItems.TextColorSubHeading;
        lblID.TextColor = AttributeItems.TextColorHeading;

        // Show attendance percentage
        switch (item.AttendanceStatusID)
        {
            case 0:
                if (item.IsParent)
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageOnSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                else
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageOffSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                lblPercentage.TextColor = AttributeItems.PercentagePositiveColor;
                lblPercentage.Text = item.AttendanceStatus + " " + item.Percentage.ToString("#.##") + "%";
                break;
            case 1:
                if (item.IsParent)
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageFailerSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                else
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageOffSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                lblPercentage.TextColor = AttributeItems.TextColorWarning;
                lblPercentage.Text = item.AttendanceStatus + " " + item.Percentage.ToString("#.##") + "%";
                break;
            case 2:
                if (item.IsParent)
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageFailerSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                else
                    btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageOffSwitch, UIControlState.Normal);
                lblPercentage.TextColor = AttributeItems.TextColorFailureWarning;
                lblPercentage.Text = item.AttendanceStatus + " " + item.Percentage.ToString("#.##") + "%";
                break;
            case 3:
                btnSwitch.SetBackgroundImage(AttributeItems.ImageFailerSwitch, UIControlState.Disabled);
                btnSwitch.Enabled = false;
                lblPercentage.TextColor = AttributeItems.TextColorFailureNotice;
                lblPercentage.Text = item.AttendanceStatus + " " + item.Percentage.ToString("#.##") + "%";
                break;
        }
    }
```

Guide me what is reason behind this. How I can solve this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code where you create your cell

Comment: I update question with code sample.

Comment: Does your UpdateCell() method set the images?  If it does not, the cell will retain the image it had when it was recycled.

Comment: Yes, I added updateCell code in post. Check it, it's conditional base image changing.

Comment: I would debug your custom cell code to verify that it is correctly updating the image when the cell is recycled.